# Trying to connect router to swiss coax plug

Tags: router, isp

I have a dsl-ac68u DSL router. It has RJ11 and RJ45 plugs. Plug in the wall only has a coaxial output. Can I go around my ISP's router/modem and connect directly my router to the wall? If so, how? Should I get an Coaxial to RJ45 adapter? Please don't laugh at me, if I am not thinking correctly :( ;)

Comment: Home networking questions are off topic here. You can ask them on [su].

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have confused with connectors and the use case where Co-axial to RJ45 adapters.

If your ISP is providing connection to your home via Co-axial cable then you should get the Modem provided by ISP or any modem which is available at the market which support Coax(Something like Motorola Surfboard series).

If you not plan to buy the modem provided by the ISP then you should also check with your ISP whether they will support third party provided supported Modems or not? Technically,the third party modem should work but sometimes ISP refuse the authenticate the third party modems in their ACS.

I will suggest you to buy/procure the modem provided buy ISP and Connect the Ethernet output of the modem to the WAN port of your ASUS Modem.